# Error logging (in catch block of try-catch) iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my code, if an exception arises, then I want to convert that exception into an error and then want to hit a service (to log this error on server). Does anybody has any idea, how to do it? 
One more question, suppose I have a method which calls another method (of another class) which in turn calls another method of any other class, that is, method A of class A calls method B of class B, which calls method C of class C. So, where should I put the try-catch block in my code? (in method A, in method B, in method C or in all three methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For more information on exception handling you can refer the apple documentation

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocExceptionHandling.html

Now for your next question i.e where to put the try catch block.

method A of class A calls method B of class B, which calls method C of class C, hence you can see in this process the thread will be same and the memory stack will be same also.

hence apply the try catch block in the class A. hence it will handle the exception raised by the other classes i.e B and C.(As the exception are global)

But you want that the exception of different classes should be handled individually so apply  the try catch in those classes.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the @try / @catch block anywhere.  I think the best programming practice would be to put it as close to where you think the exception is likely to be thrown from (because you can put in a very detailed error / NSLog line for the console at that point).

But anyways... what you want to do is:

```
@try {
    // do your potentially exception-throwing code here
}
@catch(NSException * e) 
{
    NSLog( @"exception thrown in method C; %@ %@", [e name], [e reason] );
    // and you could even throw in [e.userInfo description], too
}
```